# how can i get a changable number from a string?

Tags: php, string

i have an string link this:

```
<blog_lasts limit=2>
```

but this part can be change : limit=5 .
how can id get the number?

and how can i get this string from a bigger string?

Comment: Is this part of a larger XML or HTML string, or just a standalone string?

Comment: Is this a snippet from a string that is valid XML?

Comment: Please elaborate your use case

Answer (score 2):

This is using preg_match_all(). It isn't preferred for HTML/XML content, but without knowing if this can be loaded through a DOMDocument or just a string piece, this is the easiest way.

```
$str = '<blog_lasts limit=2>';
preg_match_all("/<blog_lasts limit=(.*?)>/",$str,$matches);
$num = $matches[1][0];
echo $num;
```

Comment: now how can i get this string <blog_lasts limit=2> for using in a strpos?

Comment: that's another question entirely that you would have to give more details about.

Comment: i am using a while between <blog_lasts> and </blog_lasts>. now i want to use it between <blog_lasts limit=2> and </blog_lasts>. this is a template, what more details you need?